# "well it's actually quite fast if you put it in transit speaking." What does this sentence mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9hl9iwas1k&t=2m23s

2:25

The sentence comes from a youtube video about an embarrassing situation when a girl meets her ex's new girlfriend. The girl complains about the slow journey of the subway. The other says, **"well it's actually quite fast if you put it in transit speaking."**

Is that a kind of expression in English to say "if you put it in ... speaking", which might means "if you consider ..." ?

Comment: "*Look, that slug is moving a foot a minute! That's actually amazingly fast if you put it in  **slug speaking**.*" The use of *speaking* is not idiomatic. A much better single-word replacement would be **terms**: "*Well, it's actually quite fast if you put it in transit **terms**.*" Or, better still, "*Well, it's actually quite fast **in terms of transit**.*"

Comment: At that point, the other speaker says "world". So the speaker says "if you put it in transit [pause *'world'*] speaking." They are on a metro - a mass transit system.

Comment: It's not a normal English expression, but the meaning is as Jason said. "...in transit speak" would be more acceptable.

Comment: Note that the speaker hesitates, groping for the right word; she finds an adequate word but not a very good one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

"transit speaking" is not idiomatic. A more common way of saying it would be "transit speak" or "transit terms".

They all mean "from the perspective of the transit system".